# How get offset property in Xamarin forms swipe view

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have swipe views in a list. in there I got scrolling issue so I want to get offSet of the swipe view

How do I determine swipe view offset in xamarin forms?

Answer (score 1):

We can easily use **SwipeChanging** event and it's include the **SwipeDirection** property and **offSet** property of the swipe view.

```
private void SwipeView_OnSwipeChanging(object sender, SwipeChangingEventArgs e) 
        
{
    e.offSet = 50;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please do not accept your answer after two days, it will help others who have similar issue.